# How to display a marker/waypoint in a jxmapviewer

Tags: java, openstreetmap, marker, jxmapviewer

I can't find a simple answer anywhere, so I guess I'm missing something:

I use openstreetmap in java, I made a GUI, I get a geopoint when clicking and I would like to display a marker where I clicked, I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
            GeoPosition gp2 = map.convertPointToGeoPosition(map.getMousePosition());

        Waypoint wp = new Waypoint() {

            @Override
            public GeoPosition getPosition() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return gp2;
            }
        };

        Set<Waypoint> set = null;
        set.add(wp);
        WaypointPainter<Waypoint> wpp = new WaypointPainter<Waypoint>();
        wpp.setRenderer(new WaypointRenderer<Waypoint>() {

            @Override
            public void paintWaypoint(Graphics2D g, JXMapViewer map, Waypoint waypoint) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        wpp.setWaypoints(set);
        Map.this.getJXMapViewer().setOverlayPainter(wpp);
        Map.this.getJXMapViewer().revalidate();
        Map.this.getJXMapViewer().repaint();
```

any clue why?

Answer (score 0):

because you just Override the method (`paintWaypoint()`) ,but you didn't modify the method.

so this works for me and will works for you also....

add following codes into your `paintWaypoint()` .this will draw a cross mark (**X**) on your mouse position.

```
 g.setColor(Color.RED);
 g.drawLine(-5,-5,+5,+5); 
 g.drawLine(-5,+5,+5,-5); 
 return true;
```